# When declaring relationship is not necessary in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api, navigation-properties

In EF6 we have two ways to declare relationship between two tables:

- Annotations Attributes
- Fluent API

Today (by accident) I removed one relationship between two tables and everything kept working well. I was very surprised because there was no way EF would know how those two tables are connected.

**Tables look like that:**

```
[Table("item")]
public class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        ItemNotes = new HashSet<ItemNote>();
    }
    [Key]
    [Column("itemID", TypeName = "int")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int itemID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ItemNote> ItemNotes { get; set; }
}

[Table("itemNotes")]
public class ItemNote
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id", TypeName = "int")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("itemID", TypeName = "int")]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    [Column("note", TypeName = "varchar")]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

**Fluent API:**

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("name=MyContext")
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);

        //I removed this relationship:
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasMany(i => i.ItemNotes).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(i => i.ItemId);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }    
}
```

**Here is the test I made:** It's an integration test, that connects to the real database, gets items with notes and tests the EF:

```
    [TestCase]
    public void QueryItemWithItemNotesTest()
    {
        FniContext fniContext = new FniContext();

        int itemId = fniContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT TOP(1) itemId FROM item WHERE itemId IN (SELECT itemId FROM dbo.itemNotes)").FirstOrDefault();
        var item = fniContext.Items.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(i => i.ItemNotes)
            .Where(i => i.itemID == itemId).FirstOrDefault();

        Assert.IsNotNull(item);
        Assert.Greater(item.ItemNotes.Count, 0);
    }
```

It passes! It loads all notes! **How come?!**

I kept investigating and it turned out that in case of 1:many relationship I totally don't have to have any relationship in the code. The only time I need it is with 1:1 relationship. Am I'm missing something? Most of relationships are 1:many, so does it mean Fluent API is used for 1:1 most of the time?

Comment: Even on the db level you don't really need the FK constraints when. You could test it with raw sql directly in the db with two tables without FKs.

In other words SELECT with joins works event without FK constraints.

But, the constraints are there for a reason and you should always use them : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/importance-foreign-key-constraint-tim-miles/

Well, coming back to your question, EF conventions have won in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework has some conventions that you do not need to define explicitly.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679962(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_2

> In addition to navigation properties, we recommend that you include
>   foreign key properties on the types that represent dependent objects.
>   Any property with the same data type as the principal primary key
>   property and with a name that follows one of the following formats
>   represents a foreign key for the relationship: '<navigation property
>   name><principal primary key property name>', '<principal class
>   name><primary key property name>', or '<principal primary key property
>   name>'. If multiple matches are found then precedence is given in the
>   order listed above. Foreign key detection is not case sensitive. When
>   a foreign key property is detected, Code First infers the multiplicity
>   of the relationship based on the nullability of the foreign key. If
>   the property is nullable then the relationship is registered as
>   optional; otherwise the relationship is registered as required.

Comment: Oh, so I was “lucky” cause names matched the conventions. But which names matters? C# class member name or database column name (in annotations)?

Comment: In the quote it states (although a little bit unclear), that it is about a property and its name. So it's the name of the property, not the column name in the database.

Comment: oh, sounds like you can have fake FK (and not being aware of it), without real FK in the database. I'm not sure I like it